# Error: System.NullReferenceException at combo_company.SelectedIndexChanged event

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, combobox

VS 2012, VB.net, Winforms (Desktop App) 
When I change item of combobox (combo_company. SelectedIndexChanged event), I m getting error System.NullReferenceException. 
I am trying to get value of **combo_company.SelectedItem** and **combo_company.SelectedValue**. I tried in two way to bind combobox, but what the problem is:

case 1 output: 
combo_company.SelectedItem= output OK  
combo_company.SelectedValue= System.NullReferenceException

case 2 output: 
combo_company.SelectedItem= System.Data.DataRowview 
combo_company.SelectedValue= output OK

common code for both case:

```
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    cmd.Connection = con
    Dim sql As String = "select company_name, company_id from tbl_company"
    cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, con)
    If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then con.Close()
    con.Open()
    da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    da.Fill(dt)
```

case 1 code:

```
    combo_company.DisplayMember = "company_name"
    combo_company.ValueMember = "company_id"
    If dt.Rows.Count >= 1 Then
        For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
            combo_company.Items.Add(dt.Rows(i).Item(0).ToString)
        Next
    End If
```

case 1 output: 
combo_company.SelectedItem= output OK  
combo_company.SelectedValue= System.NullReferenceException

case 2 code:

```
combo_company.DisplayMember = "company_name"
combo_company.ValueMember = "company_id"
combo_company.DataSource = dt
```

case 2 output: 
combo_company.SelectedItem= System.Data.DataRowview 
combo_company.SelectedValue= output OK

Comment: 1) Forget `combo_company.Items.Add(...)`, you have a `DataTable`, then use it as the cbox's data source. 2) Handle instead the `SelectionChangeCommitted` to get the `SelectedItem` and avoid `null` check. 3) You should dispose of the disposable objects. `da`, `cmd`, `con`, ...etc.

Comment: **Tip:** In the `SelectedIndexChanged`, to get the company: `Dim companyName As String = "" : If combo_company.SelectedIndex >= 0 Then companyName = DirectCast(combo_company.SelectedItem, DataRowView)(combo_company.DisplayMember).ToString()`.

Comment: @dr.null   Your tip gave me what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Your case 2 is what you should be doing and it is working exactly as it should. When you bind a `DataTable` to a WinForms control, the data actually comes from its `DefaultView`, which is a `DataView`. Each item in a `DataView` is a `DataRowView`, so the `SelectedItem` of the bound control will be a `DataRowView`, which is exactly what you're seeing.

You say that you want the `SelectedItem` but I don't think that's actually the case, because the `SelectedItem` is the whole row. I suspect that what you actually want is the `company_name` value from that row, i.e. the text displayed in the `ComboBox`. To get that you use the `Text` property of the `ComboBox`. The `SelectedValue` will give you the value from the column specified in the `ValueMember` and the `Text` will give you the value (as a `String`) of the column specified in the `DisplayMember`.

To elaborate on the first paragraph, complex data-binding in WinForms requires an object that implements either the `IList` interface or the `IListSource` interface. The `IListSource` interface has one method: `GetList`, which returns an `IList`. If you bind an `IList` then its items are used. If you bind an `IListSource` then its `GetList` method is called and the items of the `IList` returned are used. The `DataTable` class implements the `IListSource` interface and its `GetList` method returns its `DefaultView` property value, which is a `DataView`, which implements `IList` and contains `DataRowView` objects. When you bind a `DataTable`, the data you see is from its `DefaultView`, which is how you're able to filter and sort the bound data.

Comment: selecteditem.tostring is getting output in case 1, but not in case 2. and selectedtext.tostring is empty in case 2. I just want to display selected item's name (abc, def, ghi) and it's value (id) to process further.